# How to set up properly the Debugging for Python in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up the debug for Python3 on Visual Studio Code 1.38.0(latest) but I'm getting errors when I send F5.

I found in SO, Youtube and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) some examples/procedures in how to do it, but I'm still cannot do the debug to get working.

The path ot Python is `C:\Python3\python.exe`.

I already installed the Microsoft's [Python extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

What is missing in my debug configuration?

When I got to debug mode and send F5 in Terminal appears this error:

```
$ C:/Python3/python.exe c:\Users\MyUser\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.9.34911\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 58411
d:\Path\to\Script\test.py
C:\Python3\python.exe: can't open file 'c:UsersMyUser.vscodeextensionsms-python.python-2019.9.34911pythonFilesptvsd_launcher.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

On `settings.json` I have:

```
 {
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\d\\cygwin64\\Cygwin.bat",
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python3\\python.exe",
    "python.jediEnabled": false
}
```

On `launch.json` I have:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "Python3",
            "type":"python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        }
            ]
}
```

Comment: First try with the simplest setup. `.py` file in root of workspace, Default launch config generated by VSC.

Comment: why do you need setup.py to run a py file? No Need to use Multi Root Workspace. Just `File > Open Folder` is enough for the simplest case.

Comment: I don't know what is setup.py, just following what you suggested. After I open folder what need to do in order to debug a py script in a simple case?

Comment: Select the correct Launch config and press F5 or green triangle

Comment: How to know what is the correct launch? I followed more than one guide and still not working. May you show some example?

Comment: start with an empty `launch.json` and let VSC generate the default Python launch

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks so much for the help. I needed to uninstall VSCode and try again. Only in that way it works like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using cygwin as your shell as that isn't supported. If you wish to use a UNIX shell then please consider using WSL or Docker as those is properly supported.

Comment: The issue I found is that WSL is not available for Windows 7.

Comment: @GerCas Then I would try Docker as those are the two UNIX-based environments we support on WIndows.